# Openshift wordpress app: can't connect to mysql database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, openshift

I have just set up an openshift wordpress application environment (http://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/) but i can't get a connection to the mysql database. I added the phpmyadmin cartridge and i think i set the right information in my wp-config.

**The error i'm getting when surfing to the site:**

Error establishing a database connection

**My wp-config:**

```
$EBmysql = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL');
$EBmysqlUser = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME');
$EBmysqlPass = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD');


// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'eigenbouw');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', $EBmysqlUser);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', $EBmysqlPass);

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', $EBmysql);

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

**The log files don't contain any errors it seems:**

```
==> mysql/log/mysql_start.log <==
140318 18:34:51 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/openshift/5328c0ca50044622b20002dc/mysql//log/mysql_error.log'.
140318 18:34:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/5328c0ca50044622b20002dc/mysql/data/

==> mysql/log/mysql_error.log <==
140318 18:34:52 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140318 18:34:52  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140318 18:34:53 InnoDB: 5.5.36 started; log sequence number 2226531
140318 18:34:53 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.13.143.130'; port: 3306
140318 18:34:53 [Note]   - '127.13.143.130' resolves to '127.13.143.130';
140318 18:34:53 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.13.143.130'.
140318 18:34:53 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@ex-std-node306.prod.rhcloud.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
140318 18:34:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140318 18:34:53 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.36'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/5328c0ca50044622b20002dc/mysql//socket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

==> mysql/log/install_db.log <==
See the manual for more instructions.

You can start the MySQL daemon with:
cd /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr ; /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &

You can test the MySQL daemon with mysql-test-run.pl
cd /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/mysql-test ; perl mysql-test-run.pl

Please report any problems at http://bugs.mysql.com/


==> php/logs/access_log-20140318-000000-EST <==
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:13:15 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:16:15 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:16:22 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:16:24 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:16:26 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:16:29 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:35:42 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:35:44 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:35:45 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:36:25 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"

==> php/logs/error_log-20140318-000000-EST <==
[Tue Mar 18 18:05:29 2014] [error] [client 127.13.143.129] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Mar 18 18:05:30 2014] [error] [client 127.13.143.129] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:13 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c826
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:14 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:14 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:14 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:18 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c826
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:19 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:19 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:19 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations

==> phpmyadmin/logs/access_log-20140318-000000-EST <==
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:35:52 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/arrow_ltr.png HTTP/1.1" 200 139 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - adminHKLwWqh [18/Mar/2014:18:35:53 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=eigenbouw&token=abf8131a63f3f81249051839468aa0af&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&menuHashes=3a627a2c-d774b552-9e6d7974-08f204f8&_nocache=1395182166321431500 HTTP/1.1" 200 38411 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - adminHKLwWqh [18/Mar/2014:18:36:03 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/sql.php?db=eigenbouw&token=abf8131a63f3f81249051839468aa0af&goto=db_structure.php&table=wp_posts&pos=0&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&menuHashes=3a627a2c-d774b552-9e6d7974-08f204f8&_nocache=1395182176714675967 HTTP/1.1" 200 148961 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:36:06 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/s_fulltext.png HTTP/1.1" 200 193 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - adminHKLwWqh [18/Mar/2014:18:36:06 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts[]=tbl_structure.js&scripts[]=gis_data_editor.js HTTP/1.1" 200 31426 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:36:06 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/col_pointer.png HTTP/1.1" 200 113 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?server=1&token=abf8131a63f3f81249051839468aa0af&nocache=5539948530ltr" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:36:06 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/col_drop.png HTTP/1.1" 200 132 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?server=1&token=abf8131a63f3f81249051839468aa0af&nocache=5539948530ltr" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - adminHKLwWqh [18/Mar/2014:18:36:06 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?ajax_request=1&recent_table=1&token=abf8131a63f3f81249051839468aa0af HTTP/1.1" 200 221 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - adminHKLwWqh [18/Mar/2014:18:36:14 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?token=abf8131a63f3f81249051839468aa0af&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&menuHashes=3a627a2c-d774b552-9e6d7974-08f204f8-f835d310&_nocache=1395182187916183155 HTTP/1.1" 200 35246 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
178.116.245.86 - adminHKLwWqh [18/Mar/2014:18:36:15 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/version_check.php?&_nocache=1395182189038290343 HTTP/1.1" 200 39 "https://eigenbouw-vanhove.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"

==> phpmyadmin/logs/error_log-20140318-000000-EST <==
[Tue Mar 18 18:05:55 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 18 18:05:55 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:09 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c826
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:10 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:10 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 18 18:12:10 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:14 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c826
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:15 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:15 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 18 18:35:15 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

==> php/logs/access_log-20140318-000000-EST <==
178.116.245.86 - - [18/Mar/2014:18:37:49 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The db url is not going to work, you need to use getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') instead, and use the getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT') also if you are using a scaled application.

if you ssh into your gear and run 'env | grep MYSQL' you will see that the URL variable is not what it should be for WordPress to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the database `define` statements pulled 17 April 2015 from OpenShift's sample WordPress app:

```
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') . ':' . getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

The full wp-config.php file can be found on Github:

https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/config/wp-config.php